# DefinitelyTyped vs index.d.ts for angular library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, definitelytyped

I created a simple library with unit testing helpers for angular 1.x: https://github.com/dakolech/angular-unit-testing-helpers

And now I want to add types definitions. My question is:
Should I create `index.d.ts` file in my repository or should I create w new folder in `DefinitelyTyped` repository?

If first, then how to import angular types in this files (e.g. `ng.IScope`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred approach if possible is to include the types within your NPM package and specify their location in your package.json.

You need to include the [something].d.ts file in your project, add a "typings" property to your package.json referencing it, and publish that and your code to NPM.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html for the official documentation on this.

If your project depends on any types that don't have types included in their NPM packages, this gets more complicated. See https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-typings-field-in-packagejson for some details. You want to include a typings.json file which specifies how to get hold of your dependencies with Typings, and then tell your users to run `typings install npm:your-page`, which will give them both your type definitions and all the dependent definitions from your typings.json.

Comment: One more question: these external dependencies should be `globalDependecies` or normal `dependencies`? I think that second version should work, but with `typings install npm:your-page` command these dependencies don't want to be installed.